# How to include clean target in Makefile?

Tags: unix, makefile

I have a Makefile that looks like this

```
CXX = g++ -O2 -Wall

all: code1 code2

code1: code1.cc utilities.cc
   $(CXX) $^ -o $@

code2: code2.cc utilities.cc
   $(CXX) $^ -o $@
```

What I want to do next is to include `clean target` so that every time
I run `make` it will automatically delete the existing binary files of `code1` and `code2` before creating the new ones.

I tried to put these lines at the very end of the makefile, but it doesn't work

```
clean: 
    rm -f $@
    echo Clean done
```

What's the right way to do it?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

In makefile language `$@` means "name of the target", so `rm -f $@` translates to `rm -f clean`.

You need to specify to `rm` what exactly you want to delete, like `rm -f *.o code1 code2`

Answer (score 42):

The best thing is probably to create a variable that holds your binaries:

```
binaries=code1 code2
```

Then use that in the `all`-target, to avoid repeating:

```
all: clean $(binaries)
```

Now, you can use this with the `clean`-target, too, and just add some globs to catch object files and stuff:

```
.PHONY: clean

clean:
    rm -f $(binaries) *.o
```

Note use of the `.PHONY` to make `clean` a [pseudo-target](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Phony-Targets). This is a GNU make feature, so if you need to be portable to other make implementations, don't use it.

Comment: +1 for `.PHONY` (which is a GNU-ism, but Mostly Harmless elsewhere). However, it's a bad idea to put `clean` as a dependency of `all`; that increases build time and noise. Better to define all the *real* dependencies so that changes to source get propagated exactly as far as necessary.

Answer (score 2):

By the way it is written, clean rule is invoked only if it is explicitly called:

make clean

I think it is better, than make clean every time. If you want to do this by your way, try this:

```
CXX = g++ -O2 -Wall

all: clean code1 code2

code1: code1.cc utilities.cc
   $(CXX) $^ -o $@

code2: code2.cc utilities.cc
   $(CXX) $^ -o $@

clean: 
    rm ...
    echo Clean done
```

Comment: As qrdl explained, this is wrong. "rm -f $@" becomes "rm -f clean", which would not work.

Comment: No downvote, but usually this is a bad idea. Anything but a very small project takes some time to build from scratch, and you really don't want to have to wait that long every time you have made a small change.

Comment: bjarkef: right, I just answered to the part of auto-delete.  Thomas Padron-McCarthy: agree, and this is written in my post.

Comment: Apart from this not working, one of Makefiles' aims and strengths is that you need to recompile only what you really need to recompile, not the whole project. Cleaning everytime takes away this feature from you.

Comment: What is more, you have no guarantee that 'clean' will actually perform before 'code1' and 'code2' as there is no ordering in dependencies of 'all'.