# Trying to add a 'clean' target to a Makefile

Tags: makefile

```
CC     = g++

CFLAGS = -g -Wall -O0 -std=c++11


graph:  graph.o

        ${CC} -o graph  ${CFLAGS} graph.cpp
```

How do i go about putting clean in here to get rid of the .o files?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Note also that this Makefile won't work as expected.  You've declared a dependency on `graph.o`, but your rule builds an executable directly from `graph.cpp`.

Comment: BTW you can just set `CXXFLAGS` and let the implicit rules do their job. No need to set `CC` (which is for C) or your own rule.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would be looking at:

```
clean:
    rm -f *.o
```

this will remove all files ending with a .o extension, calling would be

```
make clean
```

also simply googling this will give you [tons of answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2635453/how-to-include-clean-target-in-makefile)